# Can't center a navigation bar inside a menu

Tags: html, css

I have made a navigation bar inside the content div,

```
<div id = "content">
<div id = "top_nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="?page=top&action=page1">page1</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=top&action=page2">page2</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=top&action=page3">page3</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

Divs:

```
#content 
{ 
width:1000px; 
margin: auto; 
height: auto; 
margin-bottom: 70px; 
}

#top_nav
{
margin: auto;
}
```

I want to center the navigation bar inside the div, but the above code won't center it does anyone have an idea of how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to specify a width for your #top_nav use display:table so that the div will have the width of it's content

```
#top_nav
{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify the width if you would like to use margin auto
try this:

```
#top_nav
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px; //insert the width
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yGVSU/)

Comment: Got there before me. +1 - Also, since it's already done anyway, here's mine: http://jsfiddle.net/mF87d/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign the width for #top_nav explcitly, e.g.

```
#top_nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
```

otherwise it makes the div 100% width and there is no margin to be automated